# deleting an inactive datastore under vSphere - dataloss?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere

So I had an inactive datastore listed on a blade server (I see the other disks on the internal SAS controller which is in an external diskshelf) besides my regular one. I deleted it, got the error message that the VMFS cannot be updated since the LUN is gone, and after it it shows me two other datastores now - but they are empty. It's running ESXi 4.1.

Could I have somehow caused any of that to be deleted?

I think the answer is no, since if I were to delete a datastore, it would have physically erased the VMFS partition signature at the drive, thus, instead of it being empty, it wouldn't even show up. when I did delete the inactive one and it didn't find the LUN, it just did a rescan, and the other VMFSs showed up, since others are using them with VMware also on the same bladecenter.

Is this correct?

Comment: What was the inactive datastore?  Was it an old one that's no longer zoned to the host, or a duplicate entry for a mounted datastore, or something else?

Comment: That's exactly my problem - I have no clue, as I inherited this system a few months back and was just cleaning up. If it's no longer zoned, then no worries, I guess. If it were a duplicate entry, even in that case I wouldn't see the LUN with a _fresh_ VMFS on it, would I? it wouldn't even list it as a datastore since it wouldn't have the VMFS headers at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're exactly right in your thinking on what happened - the new, empty ones just showed up because the remove triggered a rescan.

If the old datastore was showing as grayed out/italic text, then it was disconnected -- removing that wouldn't have any impact on other LUNs, and certainly wouldn't format anything back to a fresh VMFS partition.